# Publishing, journal-publishing and journal tags

Tags: discussion, tagging

We currently have [publishing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing), [journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/journal) and [journal-publishing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/journal-publishing). (That last one was me, this afternoon, after [discussion on chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/604949#604949).)

What do we think we should do with them? I would suggest merging journal into journal-publishing at least. What the publishing tag is for, I'm not sure.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If someone knows a better way of linking to a particular chunk of chat, please do share.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/conversation/journal-tags (click on “bookmark” on the right pane in chat to create links to parts of the chat; in the live chat it is under room > create bookmark).

Answer (score 4):

The issues surrounding how to use latex for submitting an article to a journal (eg, how to deal with disallowed packages, journals with postscript-only workflows, bundling files together for submission) and how to use latex to publish a journal issue (eg, how to combine possibly conflicting from multiple submissions, how to extract metadata and abstracts, how to generate PDF/X or PDF/A, font licensing and embedding for publication, etc) are pretty distinct. Self-publishing a book is different again (eg, which print-on-demand printers will accept latex-generated pdf, how to deal with bleeds and colour profiles and page imposition and such). Placing a TeX manuscript into a traditional publishing workflow is different again (I have no experience, but things like dealing with copyeditors, indexing professionals, book designers). I think [publishing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing) is too vague and could be broken down into {self-publishing} etc, and [journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/journal) could be more obvious like {journal-submission}.

Comment: I agree and like the journal-submission tag.  Publishing is what people like Hans Hagen do, it is not what the writer of an article for a journal does, even if the journal asks for a "camera ready" copy.

Answer (score 3):

- Merge [journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/journal) into [journal-publishing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/journal-publishing) (or make synonyms)
- Check the [publishing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing) tag for some inconsistent tagging (seems to be superfluous in places).

There's also the problem that preparing a journal publication could be similar to preparing a conference paper -- many conferences have their own fair share of idiosyncrasies as to how the submissions should be formatted. So if this seems to generate confusion, a {conference-publishing} tag may be made as a synonym to [journal-publishing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/journal-publishing), but only if necessary.

Comment: As we discussed in chat: in a way it would be better to have {academic-publishing} except that this would not be specific enough, since we want to rule out questions about thesis publishing, which doesn't have the same _sort_ of specific requirements...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really follow the recent tagging discussions, so I'm not an expert. But I wouldn't merge; at least this [journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/journal) tagged question has nothing to to with journal-publishing: [Taking notes while reading a journal paper](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8996/taking-notes-while-reading-a-journal-paper).

Comment: There's only 2 questions tagged, and the one you mention is probably best served with some other tag: {notes} perhaps? That the paper is from a journal is not relevant to the question...

Comment: @Seamus: By the way, should those questions carry _both_ {journal} and {journal-publishing}? I have nothing against it, I was just wondering.

Comment: I've just been adding the journal-publishing tag where it's appropriate. I decided not to remove the journal tag until a consensus is reached.

Comment: @Seamus: Good. By the way, Martin Tapankov has followed the suggestion in your very first comment.